# Bulk Insert Empty Columns UCS-2 Little Endian

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I have a tab delimited file to be imported using a bulk insert command.
I have a format file as follows.

```
8.0
9
1       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t"                          1     Field1             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
2       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t"                          2     Field2             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
3       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t"                          3     Field3             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
4       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t"                          4     Field4             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
5       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t"                          5     Field5             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
6       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t"                          6     Field6             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
7       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t"                          7     Field7             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
8       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t"                          8     Field8             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
9       SQLCHAR       0       0       "\r\n"                        9     Field9              "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
```

Which works fine for ANSI files, however I am receiving the file as UCS-2 Little Endian encoding.

My attempt to get this to work is to use the following amendments to the format file. Which stops any errors, but I get the right number of rows with all empty columns. I'd like to avoid converting the file if possible.

```
8.0
9
1       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t\0"                          1     Field1             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
2       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t\0"                          2     Field2             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
3       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t\0"                          3     Field3             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
4       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t\0"                          4     Field4             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
5       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t\0"                          5     Field5             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
6       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t\0"                          6     Field6             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
7       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t\0"                          7     Field7             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
8       SQLCHAR       0       50      "\t\0"                          8     Field8             "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
9       SQLCHAR       0       0       "\r\0\n\0"                      9     Field9               "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, just change SQLCHAR to SQLNCHAR

Answer (score 1):

your question helped me to get my answer to a different similar question Thanks

"\t\0" is GOLD!!! (stupid UNICODE :( )

(i already had the SQLNCHAR SQLNVARCHAR PART :) )

Answer (score 0):

What does your `BULK INSERT` statement look like?  You may need to add `DATAFILETYPE`:

```
 BULK INSERT {TableName}
 FROM '{FilePath}'
 WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar', FORMATFILE = '{FormatFilePath}')
```